# Building multiple indexes with one of them being unique in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes, mongo-collection

This is in continuation to [Building Multiple Indexes at Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666570/building-multiple-indexes-at-once), where I am currently making use of the following commands

```
db.test_collection_data.createIndex({"uId" : 1, "name" : 1}, {unique : 1})
db.test_collection_data.createIndex({"uId" : "hashed"})
db.test_collection_data.createIndex({"uId" : 1, "products" : 1})
db.test_collection_data.createIndex({"bId" : 1})
```

I want to understand what is the correct way of transforming this into a single command to be executed at the server. My failed attempts are as follows:

```
#uniqueness is lost for the first index
db.test_collection_data.createIndexes(
   [
     {"uId" : 1,"name":1},
     {"uId" : "hashed"},
     {"uId" : 1,"products":1},
     {"bId" : 1}
   ]
)


#unable to create since products are not really unique
db.test_collection_data.createIndexes(
   [
     {"uId" : 1,"name":1},
     {"uId" : "hashed"},
     {"uId" : 1,"products":1},
     {"bId" : 1}
   ],
   {
     unique: true
   }
)
```

Comment: ...and what is wrong with executing the create index statements one by one, in separate calls?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didn't want to covey anything wrong per say, but to get done with creating indexes that would almost take hours sometimes per index(almost a reindexing use case) in one shot(single screen) and then track the progress of all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This is in continuation to [Building Multiple Indexes at Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666570/building-multiple-indexes-at-once),*

There is a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41114446/8987128) provided the reference to [createIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/), The createIndexes command takes the form of `runCommand`:
you could use, [syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#dbcmd.createIndexes) and [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#example),

- change your real database name in `Your database name` and collection name in `test_collection_data`,

```
db.getSiblingDB("Your database name").runCommand(
  {
    createIndexes: "test_collection_data",
    indexes: [
        {
            key: {
                "uId": 1,
                "name": 1
            },
            unique : true,
            name: "_uId_name_"
        },
        {
            key: {
                "uId": "hashed"
            },
            name: "_uId_"
        },
        {
            key: {
                "uId": 1,
                "products": 1
            },
            name: "_uId_products_"
        },
        {
            key: {
                "bId": 1
            },
            name: "_bId_"
        }
    ]
  }
)
```